# Need to distribute 3 labels equally in a panel but changes strangely on resolution change

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel and 3 labels like so

```
----------
| Label1 |
| Label2 |
| Label3 |
----------
```

I want 33% of the panel to be label 1,2, and 3 so that they are equally distributed. Should I just use a TableLayoutPanel to accomplish this, the reason I am using Panel is because I need each set of 3 labels logically in blocks and I will have thousands of them.

The code I used so far to accomplish this is as follows

```
panel[0] = new Panel { 
               BackColor = Color.White, 
               Dock = DockStyle.Fill 
           };
label2[0] = new Label { 
                Text = "[label2]",  
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
                AutoSize = false,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter 
            };
panel[0].Controls.Add(label2[0]);

label3[0] = new Label { 
                Text = "[label3]",  
                Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, 
                AutoSize = false,     
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter 
            };
panel[0].Controls.Add(label3[0]);

label1[0] = new Label { 
                Text = "[label1]",  
                Dock = DockStyle.Top, 
                AutoSize = false,     
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter 
            };
panel[0].Controls.Add(label1[0]);
```

Right now my current effect is Label2 is slightly bigger than label1 and 3. For my purposes this effect was sort of nice for my purposes but on lower resolutions such as around 1024*768 Label 2 completely disappears or becomes way too small so the inverse happens. I don't understand exactly why this is happening nor do I understand how to distribute them evenly using a standard Panel. I am using thousands of these and I already have these inside a TableLayoutPanel so I didn't think it would be a good idea to make a bunch of TableLayoutPanels inside of TableLayoutPanels as I figure that would be overkill. What is a simple way to distribute 3 Labels equally in a regular Panel? After all I have TextAlign middle bottom top, why can't I use them to accomplish what I am doing since it is only 3 labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi CodeCamper you can set Anchor of panel to all,and labels to right and left,then u can try this.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (panel1.Height % 3 == 0)
            {
                SetLabels();
            }
            else
            {
                while (panel1.Height % 3 != 0)
                {
                    panel1.Height++;
                }

                SetLabels();
            }

        }
        private void SetLabels()
        {
            panel1.Controls["label1"].Location = new Point(1, 1);
            panel1.Controls["label1"].Height = (panel1.Height / 3);
            panel1.Controls["label1"].Width = panel1.Width;
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            panel1.Controls["label2"].Location = new Point(1, label1.Height);
            panel1.Controls["label2"].Height = label1.Height;
            panel1.Controls["label2"].Width = panel1.Width;
            label2.BackColor = Color.Purple;
            panel1.Controls["label3"].Location = new Point(1, label2.Height + label1.Height);
            panel1.Controls["label3"].Height = label1.Height;
            panel1.Controls["label3"].Width = panel1.Width;
            label3.BackColor = Color.Beige;
        }
```

and all labels AutoSize property set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Set label1 dock to top and label3 dock to bottom.
Then set label2 dock to fill autosize to false and textalign to MiddleLeft

EDIT:

set label.Tag to "makemecentered"
and add this to SizeChangedEvent of a Panel:

```
foreach (Label lab in (sender as Panel).Controls)            
    if (lab.Tag != null && lab.Tag.ToString() == "makemecentered")                
        lab.Top = (int)(sender as Panel).Height / 2 - lab.Height / 2;
```

EDIT 2:
I really don't know if my ability to read has gone... you wanted to set each of the labels to 33% so
set autosize of the labels to false
set desired textaligns

add panel SizeChanged event

```
    private void panel1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Label lab in (sender as Panel).Controls)
            lab.Height = (int) (sender as Panel).Height/3;
    }
```

and raise it on form create

This is my last edit, promise!

Comment: Maybe I am reading this incorrectly but it is still doing the same exact thing. Label 2 is larger than label 1 and 3 vertically and also I want them to be centered.